# Eclipse Pydev: Change active working set of projects with perspective

Tags: eclipse, pydev

I am using two different perspectives in Eclipse PyDev. One is for normal development, the other one is for checking code style of the team.

For checking code style, I have more projects checked out than I develop on, so I defined two working sets.

Now the problem is, that the PyDev package explorer always has the last used working set over all perspectives, not the last one in that specific perspective (so it does not save the active working set in the perspective).

Is there a way to change this behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not currently, the working set context is independent of the perspective (and thus work orthogonally).

What I usually do is that I have multiple working sets and in the PyDev package explorer usually I have the Ctrl+F10 (with focus on the PyDev package explorer) > 'top level elements' > 'working sets' options selected, then I can see all or just select one of those and 'go into' and then 'up', so, it's pretty fast to change between those.

Note that you can have the same project in more than one working set...